# "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup" on Windows 7 with KB4103718 in Dns.GetHostAddresses()

Tags: c#, dns, ip-address, lookup, remoting

Starting in may-8-2018, I found an error in some customers related to the early Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 updates.

The error consist in an "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup" exception when executing the .NET Framework 2.0 System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses() method giving the local host name, obtained via Dns.GetHostName(). Prevously to that updates, the method worked fine.
I use .NET 2.0 Framework beacuse I need the same program running in Windows XP, 7, 8.1, 10, Server 2003, Server 2008, etc, thus change the .NET Framework version is not a solution.

Can you help me?
Regards.

Comment: Solved updating Windows 10 to KB4284848.

Answer (score 3):

For others that continue having this problem, here's one thing my team and I discovered. Specifically, we were using Oracle's Managed Data Access component which makes a connection across the network using System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses, but would fail with the same Exception.  Note that we already had KB4284848 installed, and were noticing the same problem with Windows 7 and 10.

The network share we were testing was the one available through the user profile. Even running a custom program that would do a single lookup with System.Dns had the same issue.  Moving the program to another drive that was mapped via Group Policy worked.  I still do not know why, but that's our path forward on this.

Comment: The problem started with W10 update 1803. In that version, an error in the SMB1 protocol do not allows applications to do any network operations where the starting EXE file is located in a network drive. This was solved installing KB4284848, as I mentioned above. Another solution is to upgrade the network connected computers (servers and workstations) to use SMB2 or SMB3.